# How can i test iphone application for memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

What are the methods/tools i can use to check if in my application for iphone there are no memory leaks? Or how to find and fix them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Have you used Xcode's "build and analyse" capabilities? Had a look at instruments? Checked out NSZombie?)

Comment: No. I've just wrote the app. It's my first app in xcode. It's working but i want to ensure myself everything is ok

Comment: Cool - you'll find there's quite a bit built into the Xcode to help you along the way. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use instruments: First build and install your app on the simulator. Stop the process again (the red shield where it says "task"), then go to Run->Run with perfomance tool->Leaks. This will start Instruments preconfigured with a Leaks and memory allocation tool. For more info check out Apple's Memory Usage Performance Guidelines (which also has a section on finding leaks): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.html

Answer (score 3):

in xcode 5 just go to **product -> analyse** ... then see the list of the **memory leaks break** point...
**just go throw the break point and try to release those are not required  variable and class object** ....

http://www.streamingcolour.com/blog/tutorials/tracking-iphone-memory-leaks/

Or

This tool tells you what library is leaking, then you can debug your code as you deem suitable. If it is well organized, you will be able to see immediately what object is leaking and fix the problem with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Why it's simple! Just run the leaks performance tool. Press the following: Run -> Start with Performance Tool -> Leaks.

This tool tells you what library is leaking, then you can debug your code as you deem suitable. If it is well organized, you will be able to see immediately what object is leaking and fix the problem with ease.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the tools from XCode, Leaks tool, CPU sampler, Allocations, Activity monitor.You can find them in the menu Run->Run with performance tools.

It would be ideal to have a device attached to your machine in order to run the tools over the installed app.

Here you'll find an introduction to [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).